# Why am I getting this "split package" warning?

Tags: maven, osgi, apache-karaf

I'm building a .kar-file, but when I run `mvn package` I'm getting this error:

```
[INFO] --- maven-bundle-plugin:2.4.0:bundle (default-bundle) @ common ---
[WARNING] Bundle se.eman.path.to.my.package:common:bundle:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT : Split package, multiple jars provide the same package:com/sun/xml/bind/v2
Use Import/Export Package directive -split-package:=(merge-first|merge-last|error|first) to get rid of this warning
Package found in   [Jar:jaxb-impl, Jar:jaxb-core]
Class path         [Jar:., Jar:camel-core, Jar:slf4j-api, Jar:jaxb-impl, Jar:jaxb-core, Jar:jaxb-api, Jar:istack-commons-runtime, Jar:FastInfoset, Jar:jsr173_api, Jar:camel-groovy, Jar:groovy-all, Jar:commons-logging, Jar:slf4j-log4j12, 
Jar:log4j]
[WARNING] Bundle se.eman.path.to.my.package:common:bundle:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT : Split package, multiple jars provide the same package:com/sun/istack
Use Import/Export Package directive -split-package:=(merge-first|merge-last|error|first) to get rid of this warning
Package found in   [Jar:jaxb-core, Jar:istack-commons-runtime]
Class path         [Jar:., Jar:camel-core, Jar:slf4j-api, Jar:jaxb-impl, Jar:jaxb-core, Jar:jaxb-api, Jar:istack-commons-runtime, Jar:FastInfoset, Jar:jsr173_api, Jar:camel-groovy, Jar:groovy-all, Jar:commons-logging, Jar:slf4j-log4j12, 
Jar:log4j]
[WARNING] Bundle se.eman.path.to.my.package:common:bundle:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT : Split package, multiple jars provide the same package:com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/impl
Use Import/Export Package directive -split-package:=(merge-first|merge-last|error|first) to get rid of this warning
Package found in   [Jar:jaxb-impl, Jar:jaxb-core]
Class path         [Jar:., Jar:camel-core, Jar:slf4j-api, Jar:jaxb-impl, Jar:jaxb-core, Jar:jaxb-api, Jar:istack-commons-runtime, Jar:FastInfoset, Jar:jsr173_api, Jar:camel-groovy, Jar:groovy-all, Jar:commons-logging, Jar:slf4j-log4j12, 
Jar:log4j]
[WARNING] Bundle se.eman.path.to.my.package:common:bundle:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT : Split package, multiple jars provide the same package:com/sun/xml/bind/marshaller
Use Import/Export Package directive -split-package:=(merge-first|merge-last|error|first) to get rid of this warning
Package found in   [Jar:jaxb-impl, Jar:jaxb-core]
Class path         [Jar:., Jar:camel-core, Jar:slf4j-api, Jar:jaxb-impl, Jar:jaxb-core, Jar:jaxb-api, Jar:istack-commons-runtime, Jar:FastInfoset, Jar:jsr173_api, Jar:camel-groovy, Jar:groovy-all, Jar:commons-logging, Jar:slf4j-log4j12, 
Jar:log4j]
[WARNING] Bundle se.eman.path.to.my.package:common:bundle:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT : Split package, multiple jars provide the same package:com/sun/xml/bind/v2/runtime/unmarshaller
Use Import/Export Package directive -split-package:=(merge-first|merge-last|error|first) to get rid of this warning
Package found in   [Jar:jaxb-impl, Jar:jaxb-core]
Class path         [Jar:., Jar:camel-core, Jar:slf4j-api, Jar:jaxb-impl, Jar:jaxb-core, Jar:jaxb-api, Jar:istack-commons-runtime, Jar:FastInfoset, Jar:jsr173_api, Jar:camel-groovy, Jar:groovy-all, Jar:commons-logging, Jar:slf4j-log4j12, 
Jar:log4j]
[WARNING] Bundle se.eman.path.to.my.package:common:bundle:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT : Split package, multiple jars provide the same package:com/sun/xml/bind/util
Use Import/Export Package directive -split-package:=(merge-first|merge-last|error|first) to get rid of this warning
Package found in   [Jar:jaxb-impl, Jar:jaxb-core]
Class path         [Jar:., Jar:camel-core, Jar:slf4j-api, Jar:jaxb-impl, Jar:jaxb-core, Jar:jaxb-api, Jar:istack-commons-runtime, Jar:FastInfoset, Jar:jsr173_api, Jar:camel-groovy, Jar:groovy-all, Jar:commons-logging, Jar:slf4j-log4j12, 
Jar:log4j]
[WARNING] Bundle se.eman.path.to.my.package:common:bundle:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT : Split package, multiple jars provide the same package:com/sun/xml/bind/unmarshaller
Use Import/Export Package directive -split-package:=(merge-first|merge-last|error|first) to get rid of this warning
Package found in   [Jar:jaxb-impl, Jar:jaxb-core]
Class path         [Jar:., Jar:camel-core, Jar:slf4j-api, Jar:jaxb-impl, Jar:jaxb-core, Jar:jaxb-api, Jar:istack-commons-runtime, Jar:FastInfoset, Jar:jsr173_api, Jar:camel-groovy, Jar:groovy-all, Jar:commons-logging, Jar:slf4j-log4j12, 
Jar:log4j]
[WARNING] Bundle se.eman.path.to.my.package:common:bundle:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT : Split package, multiple jars provide the same package:com/sun/istack/logging
Use Import/Export Package directive -split-package:=(merge-first|merge-last|error|first) to get rid of this warning
Package found in   [Jar:jaxb-core, Jar:istack-commons-runtime]
Class path         [Jar:., Jar:camel-core, Jar:slf4j-api, Jar:jaxb-impl, Jar:jaxb-core, Jar:jaxb-api, Jar:istack-commons-runtime, Jar:FastInfoset, Jar:jsr173_api, Jar:camel-groovy, Jar:groovy-all, Jar:commons-logging, Jar:slf4j-log4j12, 
Jar:log4j]
[WARNING] Bundle se.eman.path.to.my.package:common:bundle:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT : Split package, multiple jars provide the same package:com/sun/xml/bind/api
Use Import/Export Package directive -split-package:=(merge-first|merge-last|error|first) to get rid of this warning
Package found in   [Jar:jaxb-impl, Jar:jaxb-core]
Class path         [Jar:., Jar:camel-core, Jar:slf4j-api, Jar:jaxb-impl, Jar:jaxb-core, Jar:jaxb-api, Jar:istack-commons-runtime, Jar:FastInfoset, Jar:jsr173_api, Jar:camel-groovy, Jar:groovy-all, Jar:commons-logging, Jar:slf4j-log4j12, 
Jar:log4j]
[WARNING] Bundle se.eman.path.to.my.package:common:bundle:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT : Split package, multiple jars provide the same package:com/sun/xml/bind
Use Import/Export Package directive -split-package:=(merge-first|merge-last|error|first) to get rid of this warning
Package found in   [Jar:jaxb-impl, Jar:jaxb-core]
Class path         [Jar:., Jar:camel-core, Jar:slf4j-api, Jar:jaxb-impl, Jar:jaxb-core, Jar:jaxb-api, Jar:istack-commons-runtime, Jar:FastInfoset, Jar:jsr173_api, Jar:camel-groovy, Jar:groovy-all, Jar:commons-logging, Jar:slf4j-log4j12, 
Jar:log4j]
[WARNING] Bundle se.eman.path.to.my.package:common:bundle:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT : Split package, multiple jars provide the same package:com/sun/xml/bind/v2/util
Use Import/Export Package directive -split-package:=(merge-first|merge-last|error|first) to get rid of this warning
Package found in   [Jar:jaxb-impl, Jar:jaxb-core]
Class path         [Jar:., Jar:camel-core, Jar:slf4j-api, Jar:jaxb-impl, Jar:jaxb-core, Jar:jaxb-api, Jar:istack-commons-runtime, Jar:FastInfoset, Jar:jsr173_api, Jar:camel-groovy, Jar:groovy-all, Jar:commons-logging, Jar:slf4j-log4j12, 
Jar:log4j]
[WARNING] Bundle se.eman.path.to.my.package:common:bundle:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT : Split package, multiple jars provide the same package:com/sun/xml/bind/v2/runtime
Use Import/Export Package directive -split-package:=(merge-first|merge-last|error|first) to get rid of this warning
Package found in   [Jar:jaxb-impl, Jar:jaxb-core]
Class path         [Jar:., Jar:camel-core, Jar:slf4j-api, Jar:jaxb-impl, Jar:jaxb-core, Jar:jaxb-api, Jar:istack-commons-runtime, Jar:FastInfoset, Jar:jsr173_api, Jar:camel-groovy, Jar:groovy-all, Jar:commons-logging, Jar:slf4j-log4j12, 
Jar:log4j]
[WARNING] Bundle se.eman.path.to.my.package:common:bundle:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT : Split package, multiple jars provide the same package:com/sun/istack/localization
Use Import/Export Package directive -split-package:=(merge-first|merge-last|error|first) to get rid of this warning
Package found in   [Jar:jaxb-core, Jar:istack-commons-runtime]
Class path         [Jar:., Jar:camel-core, Jar:slf4j-api, Jar:jaxb-impl, Jar:jaxb-core, Jar:jaxb-api, Jar:istack-commons-runtime, Jar:FastInfoset, Jar:jsr173_api, Jar:camel-groovy, Jar:groovy-all, Jar:commons-logging, Jar:slf4j-log4j12, 
Jar:log4j]
[WARNING] Bundle se.eman.path.to.my.package:common:bundle:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT : Split package, multiple jars provide the same package:com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/annotation
Use Import/Export Package directive -split-package:=(merge-first|merge-last|error|first) to get rid of this warning
Package found in   [Jar:jaxb-impl, Jar:jaxb-core]
Class path         [Jar:., Jar:camel-core, Jar:slf4j-api, Jar:jaxb-impl, Jar:jaxb-core, Jar:jaxb-api, Jar:istack-commons-runtime, Jar:FastInfoset, Jar:jsr173_api, Jar:camel-groovy, Jar:groovy-all, Jar:commons-logging, Jar:slf4j-log4j12, 
Jar:log4j]
```

My pom .xml:

```
<packaging>bundle</packaging>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.groupId}.common</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Bundle-Name>${project.name}</Bundle-Name>
                    <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
                    <!-- TODO: Insert your needed exports here -->
                    <Export-Package>*,se.eman.path.to.my.package.*</Export-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>${camel-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-groovy</artifactId>
        <version>${camel-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-test</artifactId>
        <version>${camel-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-test-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${camel-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I just can't figure out what's causing these errors. When I read up on split package I get the very helpful advice that split package should be avoided. Yeah... I have no control what so ever over jaxb-impl, jaxb-core or com/sun/*.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default value for Export-Package is `{local-packages}` and not *

With the directive `Export-Package: *`, you are asking  bnd to export all the dependencies of your project.

Remove the * or use `{local-packages}`

**Edit** :

Note that you should only export public API from a Bundle. Everything else should be keep private. By default, maven-bundle-plugin export all packages, except package containing `impl` or `internal`. If you can, you should stick with this convention and omit the `Export-Package` directive, or explicitly export your public packages.

Comment: This may have worked, but exporting all of `{local-packages}` is also a very bad practice. You should only export the packages that form your public-facing API. Everything else should be internal/private.

Answer (score 3):

Please check http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/felix-users/200709.mbox/%3CF034315F398DE24C9A76FB51DAFAB709FC9638@nets13ga.ww300.siemens.net%3E

Sample worked for me :

```
<Export-Package>
  org.hibernate.*;version=${pkgVersion};-split-package:=merge-last                       

</Export-Package>
```

same answer at ; 
[Use third party artifacts with split packages in Maven and Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49805394/use-third-party-artifacts-with-split-packages-in-maven-and-java-9/56613771#56613771)

Comment: This also works inside instruction `Private-Package` when you declare import dependencies into a bundle and different jar contain the same class. This worked for me.