# Use third party artifacts with split packages in Maven and Java 9

Tags: java, maven, java-9, java-module

I am trying to make my project ready for Java 9 and I am running into problems with split packages (artifacts sharing the same package).

My application depends on at least two third-party legacy artifacts (that are built with Java <9). When I run Maven with Java 9, I get:

```
[ERROR] module myapp reads package P from both A and B
```

Which is correct, since the package P exists in A.jar and B.jar, but without overlapping classes. I understand that this is a problem for Java 9 and I studied suggested solutions in  https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-9-migration-guide/#fixes-2 . To summarize it is either "Fix your code" (not possible, since third-party JAR) or "Run with command line options" (Where the most interesting may be `--patch-module <package>=<path-to-jar>`).
There was another idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41385229/how-can-i-handle-split-packages-in-automatic-modules), which said

> wrap one of the 3rd party modules (or both) in a simple module, which does nothing but explicitly exports only the package(s) that are actually needed by your module.

But how can I achieve this in Maven (3.5.0), where all I currently have is a `<dependency>` and the maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0  - and I don't want to statically repackage third party JARs?

Any hint or pointer to an example would be welcome.

Comment: To not use modules?

Comment: As funny as that sounds, that was indeed helpful. When removing the module-info.java from my projects, Maven stopped complaining about the split package. So, thanks. ;-)

Still - isn't there a way that allows to keep the module-info.java ?

Comment: I'm afraid no. If you create *module-info.java* then you, in fact, start using named modules and module-path with all their limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Please check 
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/felix-users/200709.mbox/%3CF034315F398DE24C9A76FB51DAFAB709FC9638@nets13ga.ww300.siemens.net%3E

Sample worked for me :

```
<Export-Package>
  org.hibernate.*;version=${pkgVersion};-split-package:=merge-last                       

</Export-Package>
```

Same answer at : 
[Why am I getting this "split package" warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35412390/why-am-i-getting-this-split-package-warning/56613815#56613815)